# Automatic draft when hitting reply button

Tags: vba, outlook

Suppose I get a mail from "Lastname, Firstname" Content: "Hi, we wait for your answer" and i want to reply to it.
Is there a way that as soon as i hit the Reply button, instead of

---

```
From: "Lastname, Firstname" firstname.lastname@mail.com
Sent: Monday, 14. November 2017 12:23
To: sample@mailc.com
Subject: Draft

Hi, we wait for you
```

---

**I would get instead a draft, that i could edit.**

---

```
Hi firstname,

thank you for your message!

Kind regards


From: me@mail.com 
Sent: Monday, 14. November 2017 12:23
To: sample@mailc.com
Subject: Draft

Hi, we wait for you
```

---

Comment: Does Quick Steps in Outlook cover this? https://www.msoutlook.info/question/reply-with-a-message-template-via-quick-steps

Comment: almost yes! I dont see a way to dynamically insert the Name, but it covers the rest! Thanks and feel free to add it as an answer so i can upvote!

Comment: Have added. You are dynamically trying to add the sender's name?

Comment: yes, see in the question: "Hi [firstname]"

Answer (score 1):

From version Excel 2010 onwards you can create a boilerplate template with custom text incorporating many of your desired features using Quick Steps.

In case this [link](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/reply-with-a-message-template-via-quick-steps) dies here are the edited screenshot highlights:

[image: First screenshot]

[image: Second screenshot]

[image: Third screenshot]

[image: Fourth screenshot]

[image: Fifth screenshot]